# Proxy в android

Tags: java, android, webview, proxy

Необходимо сделать в приложении своё локальное прокси, такой сказать поднять свой прокси сервер(например localhost:5566) и через него пустить WebView. Как задать свой прокси WebView я нашёл. Но вот как создать локальный прокси, не очень понял. Может кто с таким сталкивался уже?

Код для установки прокси WebView:

```
private boolean setProxyHostField(HttpHost proxyServer) {
// Getting network      
Class networkClass = null;
Object network = null;
try {
    networkClass = Class.forName("android.webkit.Network");
    Field networkField = networkClass.getDeclaredField("sNetwork");
    network = getFieldValueSafely(networkField, null);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.e(ProxyManager.class.getName(), "error getting network");
    return false;
}
if (network == null) {
    Log.e(ProxyManager.class.getName(), "error getting network : null");
    return false;
}
Object requestQueue = null;
try {
    Field requestQueueField = networkClass
            .getDeclaredField("mRequestQueue");
    requestQueue = getFieldValueSafely(requestQueueField, network);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.e(ProxyManager.class.getName(), "error getting field value");
    return false;
}
if (requestQueue == null) {
    Log.e(ProxyManager.class.getName(), "Request queue is null");
    return false;
}
Field proxyHostField = null;
try {
    Class requestQueueClass = Class.forName("android.net.http.RequestQueue");
    proxyHostField = requestQueueClass
            .getDeclaredField("mProxyHost");
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.e(ProxyManager.class.getName(), "error getting proxy host field");
    return false;
}       
synchronized (synchronizer) {
    boolean temp = proxyHostField.isAccessible();
    try {
        proxyHostField.setAccessible(true);
        proxyHostField.set(requestQueue, proxyServer);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(ProxyManager.class.getName(), "error setting proxy host");
    } finally {
        proxyHostField.setAccessible(temp);
    }
}
return true;
}

private Object getFieldValueSafely(Field field, Object classInstance) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
boolean oldAccessibleValue = field.isAccessible();
field.setAccessible(true);
Object result = field.get(classInstance);
field.setAccessible(oldAccessibleValue);
return result;      
}
```